# Flutter mockito unit test error after migrate null-safety

Tags: flutter, mockito, flutter-test

> Null* get any
> package:mockito/src/mock.dart

An argument matcher that matches any argument passed in "this" position.

The argument type 'Null*' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Params'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)

```
  test('should start listening when StartListening is called', () async {
final tStreamListHazardEntity =
    Stream<List<HazardEntity>>.fromIterable([tListHazardEntity]);

// arrange
when(mockHazardListen!.call(any))
    .thenAnswer((_) async => Right(tStreamListHazardEntity));
// assert
expectLater(
    bloc,
    emitsInOrder([
      isA<HazardMasterInitial>(),
      isA<Loading>(),
      isA<UpdateState>()
    ]));

// act
bloc!.add(StartListening());
await untilCalled(mockHazardListen!.call(any));

// assert
verify(mockHazardListen!.call(any)); });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, Used mockito can creating mocks without creating manual mocks when after flutter null-safety migration .

> Mock library for Dart inspired by mockito.

Mocktail focuses on providing a familiar, simple API for creating mocks in Dart (with null-safety) without the need for manual mocks or code generation.